# Ribbon Invalidate makes my outlook add-in crash

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, ribbon, invalidation

I have a pretty large outlook add-in with following `ribbon.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabMail">
    <group id="groupViewHome" label="View tasks">
      <toggleButton id="buttonToggleHistoryHome" getLabel="getLabelToggleHistory" imageMso="ControlToggleButton" onAction="toggleHistory_Click" size="large" getPressed="getEnabledToggleHistory" />
    </group>
      </tab>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="DCP">
    <group id="groupCreateTask" label="Create a task">
      <button id="buttonNewTask" label="New Task" imageMso="QueryAppend" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" size="large" getEnabled="getMailSelected" />
    </group>
    <group id="groupEdit" label="Edit a task">
      <button id="buttonAddSelection" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="QueryUpdate" onAction="selectedText_Click" size="large" getEnabled="getMailAndIDSelected"/>
    </group>
    <group id="groupView" label="View tasks">
      <button id="buttonTaskHistory" imageMso="FileDocumentInspect" onAction="taskInfo_Click" getLabel="getButtonHistoryLabel" />
      <toggleButton id="buttonToggleHistory" getLabel="getLabelToggleHistory" imageMso="ControlToggleButton" onAction="toggleHistory_Click" getPressed="getEnabledToggleHistory" />
      <checkBox id="buttonTriggerMail" label="Toggle auto-history" onAction="Trigger_Click" getPressed="getInitialTriggerState"/>
    </group>
    <group id="groupAttach" label="Attachments">
      <button id="saveMail2" label="Add mail as .msg attachment" imageMso="AttachItem" onAction="saveMail_Click" getEnabled="getMailAndIDSelected"/>
      <button id="selectAttach" label="Select attachments to add" imageMso="AttachMenu" onAction="selectAttach_Click" getEnabled="getMailAndIDSelectedAndAttach"/>
    </group>
    <group id="groupLinks" label="Hyperlinks">
      <button id="addLinkToMail" label="Add task link to mail body" imageMso="HyperlinkInsert" onAction="addLink_Click" size="large" getEnabled="getMailAndIDSelected"/>
    </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText">
      <menu id="dcp" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click"/>
    <button id="addTask" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTable">
      <menu id="dcp3" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText2" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click"/>
    <button id="addTask3" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTableCell">
      <menu id="dcp4" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText3" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click"/>
    <button id="addTask4" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailListTable">
      <menu id="dcp5" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText4" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click"/>
    <button id="addTask5" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailPictureTable">
      <menu id="dcp6" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText5" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click" />
    <button id="addTask6" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTextTable">
      <menu id="dcp7" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText6" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click"/>
    <button id="addTask7" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailTableWhole">
      <menu id="dcp8" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText7" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click" />
    <button id="addTask8" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailList">
      <menu id="dcp9" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText8" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click" />
    <button id="addTask9" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailHyperlink">
      <menu id="dcp10" label="DCP">
    <button id="selectedText9" label="Copy selection to task" imageMso="CitationInsert" onAction="selectedText_Click" />
    <button id="addTask10" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <menu id="dcp2" label="DCP">
    <button id="buttonTaskHistoryMail" label="View task history" imageMso="SourceControlShowHistory" onAction="taskInfo_Click" />
    <button id="addTask2" label="New task" imageMso="GoToNewRecord" onAction="buttonNewTask_Click" />
    <button id="saveMail" label="Add mail as .msg attachment" imageMso="AttachItem" onAction="saveMail_Click" />
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuAttachments">
    <button id="buttonAddAttachment" label="Add attachment to task" imageMso="AttachMenu" onAction="addAttachment_Click"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

As you can see I have a couple of actions that require invalidation to enable, toggle... my buttons. My add-in starts up fine but crashes on some occasions. The following are some examples on which the add-in almost always crashes:

- Opening a mail item in a new inspector window and closing it again
- Multiple windows open, context menu with custom button in it is opened

The occasions in which it occurs make me pretty sure it has everything to do with the automatic invalidation on creation of a new context menu or ribbon, not when I call it myself. The error does not persist when I remove the getEnabled, getPressed... attributes. I can't figure out a way to surpress the error instead of crashing or how to fix it. So if anybody can help or can give me more info on this it would be much appreciated. If you need any more code (like the getEnabled, getPressed... methods), let me know.

My invalidate methods. Note that most just return a boolean. These booleans are kept as a private variable inside the ribbon.cs class

```
public bool getEnabledToggleHistory(IRibbonControl control)
{
   return toggleHistoryPanelState;
}

public bool getMailSelected(IRibbonControl control)
{
    try
    {
        MailItem mailItem = getMail();
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public bool getMailAndIDSelected(IRibbonControl control)
{
    return mailAndIDSelected;
}

public bool getMailAndIDSelectedAndAttach(IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (hasAttachments && mailAndIDSelected)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I debug in a new Visual Studio instance I get the following:

`Unhandled exception at 0x70B5B2A7 (MSO.DLL) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.`

If I debug the code from my solution I can never catch the error, nor does it say it has an unhandled one. It just crashes.

Comment: put up your behind C# - how to tell anything from this :)

Comment: My methods needed for invalidate are really simple and most likely not the problem. However I'll post some if you want

Comment: I edited my question to show you the methods for invalidating

Comment: it's not what I want :) - run it in debug and try to catch to see what's going on - you can pretty much get most of the errors - or log.  Isolate and remove everything else but the 'culprits' that cause issue - that'd narrow it down. It could be many things w/ OL, hard to say, make it more specific - I can help but need something

Comment: yep, that's OL - if you can't catch it or log (don't just catch exceptions, put something to dump - you can dump into temp user folder) - my best suggestion, the good old divide and conquer - remove everything (you already said only 'flags' are causing it), just leave one button with one thing in it - 'return' all methods until you get one causing all the problems - something like that...

Comment: and just saw it - you have the last `ContextMenuAttachments` w/o a `menu` - just a button (I don't recall context menus, how it's done) - might be that? check id-s for duplicate etc.

Comment: "don't just catch exceptions, put something to dump - you can dump into temp user folder" You mean putting streamwriters in my code that log messages to a file?

Comment: or using some logger (google, there're many) - I have my own class using since BC :)

Comment: Context menu's can have both buttons inside as menu's. I use the menu for when I'm adding multiple options, adding buttons straight into the context menu is the most known way. No duplicate ID's either, I receive errors on that when I build my code if I have duplicates.

Comment: ...that OL XML system for ribbons etc. is very error prone - so you need to check everything (be meticulous) - and OL errors aren't very descriptive, most of the time just crashes. Btw what happens if you just remove the whole context-menu?

Comment: Then there are only the standard buttons, no custom ones...

Comment: I think I found my mistake, thanks to you. Narrowed it down to the `getMailSelected` method. called the `getMail` method from outside my invalidate and set a static bool accordingly (just like in the other methods). No crashes so far... Thanks man

Comment: super :) can I post an answer then for you to mark that? Even though it's not much of an answer, if it did help :), cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(posting sort of an 'answer' based on our discussion in the comments)

If you can't catch it or log (**don't just catch exceptions, put something into dump** - you can dump into temp user folder)...

My best suggestion, `the good old divide and conquer` - remove everything (you already said only 'flags' are causing it), just leave one button with one thing in it - 'return' all methods **until you get one causing all the problems** - something like that.

(OL XML system for ribbons etc. is very error prone - so you need to check everything (be meticulous) - and OL errors aren't very descriptive, most of the time just crashes. Btw what happens if you just remove the whole context-menu?)